# Why is the complexity of this program O(n)?

Tags: c++

Why is the complexity of this program O(n)? There is a `while` loop inside the `for` loop. Doesn't that make the complexity O(n^2)?

[image]

Comment: Mind adding your code into a code block instead?

Comment: each `while` has `k` iterations, `for` has about `n/2k` iterations, so total it’s `O(n)`

Comment: Pay attention to how `i` is incremented.

Comment: The comment above `right` is not correct. Since the loop guarantees that 2k < n, 2k can't be a multiple of n. It would be correct if it said the reverse - "when n is not a multiple of 2 * k" - or said "divisor" instead of "multiple".

Answer (score 0):

Every element in the array is accessed exactly one time. This has the complexity of O(N).

The outside loop does not do `N` iterations, the number of iterations of the outside loop `N/k`, multiplied by the number of iterations of the inside loop `k/2` gives the total number of the iterations `N/k * k/2 = N/2` -- that's `O(N)`

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to complexity, first identify two things:

1. size of input
2. basic operation

In your case, the size of input is the size `n` of your array `arr`, while the basic operation is `swap`.

Then answer this question:

> If size of input `n` doubles, how many more basic operations `swap` do you need to do?

After some analysis, you will reach the conclusion that you also need to double the number of `swap` operations, because each element in the array `arr` is swapped exactly once.

So the complexity is `O(N)`, i.e. linear to the size of input.